# Failing to pass variable of struct-array as function parameter

Tags: c, struct

I am fairly new to the concept of structs in C, and have run into a problem. I have looked for any similar problems posted here, but cannot find any. What I am trying to do is pass a variable in an array of structs as a parameter in a function, as so:

```
struct Student
{
    float average;
    int ID;
    int grades[5];
    char firstName[20], lastName[20];
};

void main(void)
{
    struct Student sTable[10];

    float maxAverage(float sTable[].average)
    {
        int i;
        float max = 0;

        for(i = 0;i < 10; ++i)
        {
            if(sTable[i].value > max)
            {
                max += sTable[i].value;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }

    printf("%f",maxAverage(sTable[].average));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems here.

1. You cannot nest functions inside other functions like you can in languages like Java, C#, Python.
2. You are passing the struct array incorrectly.
3. Your main declaration is incorrect.

You want code something like this:

```
struct Student
{
    float average;
    int ID;
    int grades[5];
    char firstName[20], lastName[20];
};

float maxAverage(struct Student sTable[])
{
    int i;
    float max = 0;

    for(i = 0;i < 10; ++i)
    {
        if(sTable[i].value > max)
        {
            max += sTable[i].average;
        }
    }
    return max;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct Student sTable[10];
    //initialize sTable
    printf("%f", maxAverage(sTable));
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you are missing initialization of `sTable`.

What's more you really ought to pass the length of the array as a parameter to `maxAverage`. That will then allow you more flexibility to use arrays of any length.

Comment: The references to `.value` in `maxAverage` should be `.average`, I believe.

Comment: @jwodder Thanks, I just moved the code around in the editor, didn't try to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't declare or define a function inside another function, so move `maxAverage` outside of `main` (which, incidentally, should return `int`, not `void`).  Secondly, given an array of structs, you can't just automatically create an array of the values from a certain field of the structs; if you want to, you would have to manually declare a separate array of (in this case) `float`s and then copy over the `average` fields one by one.  A simpler way would be to simply pass `sTable` itself to `maxAverage` and have `maxAverage` only operate on the `average` fields of the structs in the array.